# Is this a pointer to a pointer?

Tags: c++, c

Considering the following struct declaration:

```
typedef struct
{
    UINT8  HdrLength:4;
    UINT8  Version:4;
    UINT8  TOS;
    UINT16 Length;
    UINT16 Id;
    UINT16 FragOff0;
    UINT8  TTL;
    UINT8  Protocol;
    UINT16 Checksum;
    UINT32 SrcAddr;
    UINT32 DstAddr;
} WINDIVERT_IPHDR, *PWINDIVERT_IPHDR;
```

The "*PWINDIVERT_IPHDR" being declared on the end, I've never seen this before. It appears to be that it's simply a pointer-type declaration for WINDIVERT_IPHDR struct. Is my assumption correct? If it is, would this code:

```
extern BOOL WinDivertHelperParsePacket(PVOID pPacket, UINT packetLen,
    PWINDIVERT_IPHDR *ppIpHdr, PWINDIVERT_IPV6HDR *ppIpv6Hdr,
    PWINDIVERT_ICMPHDR *ppIcmpHdr, PWINDIVERT_ICMPV6HDR *ppIcmpv6Hdr,
    PWINDIVERT_TCPHDR *ppTcpHdr, PWINDIVERT_UDPHDR *ppUdpHdr, PVOID *ppData,
    UINT *pDataLen)
```

.. specifically the `PWINDIVERT_IPHDR *ppIpHdr` mean that the method parameter "ppIpHdr" there is actually a pointer to a  pointer?

Comment: Yes, it is. That's why its name starts with `pp`, after all.

Comment: lol @Angew thanks, should I just delete the question for the sake of it being so obvious or do you care to post an answer? Thanks again, just wanted to be sure I wasn't going crazy.

Comment: Yes, you should delete it. There is really no point in answering this question beyond the comment made by @Angew.

Comment: @barakmanos A comment is not an answer, and while the question is basic, I think it deserves a proper answer (which I didn't have time to post at the time of writing the comment). I don't see a reason for deleting it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, that's a pointer-type as in the following snippet:

```
typedef struct A {
    int val;
} type, *type_ptr;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

  type obj;
  obj.val = 42;
  type_ptr ptr = &obj;
  std::cout << ptr->val; // 42

  return 0;
}
```

As a sidenote: in C you always need to prefix the `struct` keyword when declaring objects or pointers to that object. This `typedef` syntax is commonly used to avoid unnecessary verbosity.

Comment: There is really no point in answering this question beyond the comment already made by @Angew.

Comment: I realize that you're not going to delete this answer after getting an up-vote, nonetheless, the entire question is redundant once the answer "Yes" was given.

Comment: If that really annoys you I can delete it anyway. I'm not that rep-farmer although I believe I added a small something.

Comment: I'm going to leave the question because of exactly what's happening here. I hate asking C/C++ questions here because of exactly this. The response is like "this is such a simple question it's stupid that you even asked it." Well, you can see from my question that I just wanted to be sure my assumptions were true. But maybe there's someone who literally just has no idea whatsoever. It's a valid question.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire I agree, and google might think exactly the same for someone who searches these keywords.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire: I did not say or imply it was a stupid question.

Comment: @barakmanos ok it's all good, peace love and good will toward men. Thanks everyone for their input.

Answer (score 4):

This typedef declaration

```
typedef struct
{
    UINT8  HdrLength:4;
    UINT8  Version:4;
    UINT8  TOS;
    UINT16 Length;
    UINT16 Id;
    UINT16 FragOff0;
    UINT8  TTL;
    UINT8  Protocol;
    UINT16 Checksum;
    UINT32 SrcAddr;
    UINT32 DstAddr;
} WINDIVERT_IPHDR, *PWINDIVERT_IPHDR;
```

may be split in two typedef declarations

```
typedef struct
{
    UINT8  HdrLength:4;
    UINT8  Version:4;
    UINT8  TOS;
    UINT16 Length;
    UINT16 Id;
    UINT16 FragOff0;
    UINT8  TTL;
    UINT8  Protocol;
    UINT16 Checksum;
    UINT32 SrcAddr;
    UINT32 DstAddr;
} WINDIVERT_IPHDR;

typedef WINDIVERT_IPHDR *PWINDIVERT_IPHDR;
```

Thus parameter declaration

```
PWINDIVERT_UDPHDR *ppUdpHdr
```

is equivalent to

```
WINDIVERT_IPHDR * *ppUdpHdr
```